# JQuery AJAX update a textbox on another textbox textchanged

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I would like to update my input text type (id="textbox2") when i typed something at another input text type (id="textbox1").

Here's my initial code:

```
$("#textbox1").keyup(function(){
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "idgetter.php",
            data: 'id='+$("#textbox1").val(),
            success: function(n) {
                $('#textbox2').val(n);
            },
            error: function(n) {
                $('#textbox2').val(n);
            } 
       }); 
    });
```

And my idgetter.php :

```
include("inc/conn.php");
$q = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM jurnalis WHERE userid = '".$_POST['id']."'")or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
if(mysql_num_rows($q)<=0) return "none";
else{
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
return $r["name"];
```

Long story short, this did not work, any idea why?

Comment: what you see in the textbox1 ? none?

Comment: yes, only none is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In idgetter.php, Instead of returning using return give

```
echo "none";
```

and

```
echo $r["name"];
```

Comment: still only "none" appeared

Comment: Then check your query does it return any results with watever you are enetering in text field 1. Your db should have that value.

Answer (score 0):

You should try echo instead of return:

your code would be like this:

```
include("inc/conn.php");
$q = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM jurnalis WHERE userid = '".$_POST['id']."'")or    trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
if(mysql_num_rows($q)<=0) echo "none";
else{
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo $r["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there are a few amends needed in your php:

1. change return to echo (like stated in the other answers)
2. change your if statement to

   if(mysql_num_rows($q)==0){ 
     echo 'none';
   }else{
     $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
     echo $r['name'];
   }

That should do it hopefully. Also as an FYI its worth trying to avoid adding $_POST[''] items to SQL statements directly, as its prone to SQL injection breaches.